# Should I use "Por meio de" or "Através"? Are they synonyms?

Tags: vocabulário, sinônimos

We often see the expressions "**Por meio de**" and "**Através de**" being used in very similar contexts. Can I use both interchangeably?

If not, then when should I use one or the other? Are there other similar expressions in portuguese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### English

In Brazil, the expression "*através de*" (through something) has a physical meaning, related to the movement of something or someone going through something else. It conveys the idea of transpassing, crossing or piercing. To convey the idea of result, outcome or means, the expression "*por meio de*" (by means of) is more correct.

Examples:

> A flecha passou através da cortina. (The arrow pierced the curtains. -
>   it indicates physical movement)
>
> Ele obteve sucesso por meio de muito esforço. (He achieved success by
>   working hard/by means of hard working. - it indicates means)

Nevertheless, "*através de*" is commonly used as a metaphor of the physical movement to express means, particularly in the spoken language.

Example:

> Eu conheci minha namorada através da Internet. (I met my girlfriend
>   through the Internet. - it is accepted as an indication of means)

---

### Português

No Brasil a expressão "*através de*" tem significado físico, envolvendo o movimento de algo ou alguém através de algo. Por isso passa a ideia de transpassar, cruzar ou furar. Para significar resultado, decorrência ou meio, a expressão "por meio de" é mais correta.

Exemplos:

> A flecha passou através da cortina. (denota movimento físico)
>
> Ele obteve sucesso por meio de muito esforço. (denota decorrência)

Ainda assim, "através" é comumente utilizado como metáfora física para indicar decorrência, principalmente na língua falada.

Exemplo:

> Eu conheci minha namorada através da Internet. (é aceitável como
>   indicação de meio)